# Paged WP_Query is quitting on page 3

Tags: php, wp-query

I am having this problem where every time I run this, it stops on page 3. There are about 15000 products that are published. So there should be at least 30 pages.

I narrowed it down to the $loop = new WP_Query( $args ) just stopping for some reason. Not sure how to figure out what the error is.

```
function processPerPage($paged, $i) {

    if($paged) { } else { $paged = 1; }

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 500,
        'paged' => $paged
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    if($i) { } else { $i = 1; }

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

        // do product work
        $i++;   

    }

wp_reset_query();

} 

global $wpdb;
$count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'product' and post_status = 'publish'" );
$pagestotal = $count/500+1;
$paged = 1;

while($paged <= $pagestotal) {

    processPerPage($paged, $i); 
    $paged++;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop"? Is there an error message being presented anywhere? Is your website loading, or is PHP throwing a fatal error preventing that?

Comment: No error... the page just stops. I had it echo a string at each step and specify the value of paged and on paged 3 the string right before  $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); is printed on the screen but the one right after it does not. This is where it stops writing. No error, nothing.

Comment: Looks like I it is running out of memory.

Comment: One thing I'd recommend doing, regardless of this issue, is installing the [WP Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin. It'll show you things like how long your DB queries are taking, how long it took your server to process the request, how much memory your request used, as well as a ton of other super handy debugging information.